# Perform an SQL query excluding a specific partition name

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

Let's imagine that the table `my_table` is divided into 1000 partitions as the following example:

`P1, P2, P3, ... , P997, P998, P999, P1000`

Partitions are organized by dates, mostly a partition per day. E.g.:

```
P0    < 01/01/2000 => Contains around 472M records
P1    = 01/01/2000 => Contains around  15k records
P2    = 02/01/2000 => Contains around  15k records
P3    = 03/01/2000 => Contains around  15k records
...   = ../../.... => Contains around  ... records
P997  = 07/04/2000 => Contains around  15k records
P998  = 08/04/2000 => Contains around  15k records
P999  = 09/04/2000 => Contains around  15k records
P1000 = 10/04/2000 => Contains around  15k records
```

Please notice that P0 is `<` to 01/01/2000, NOT `=`

#### CURRENT SITUATION:

When looking for a specific record without knowing the date, I am doing a:
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table WHERE ... ;`
But this take too much time because it does include `P0` (30s).

#### IMPOSSIBLE SOLUTION:

So the best idea would be to execute an SQL query such as:
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table FROM PARTITION(P42) WHERE ... ;`
But we never know in which partition is the record. We don't know either the date associated to the partition. And of course we won't loop over all partitions 1 by 1

#### BAD SOLUTION:

I could be clever by doing 5 by 5:
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table FROM PARTITION(P40,P41,P42,P43,P44) WHERE ... ;`
However same issue as above, I won't loop over all partitions, even 5 by 5

#### LESS BAD SOLUTION:

I won't run either do (excluding `P0` in the list):
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table FROM PARTITION(P1,P2,...,P99,P100) WHERE ... ;`
The query would be too long and I would have to compute for each request the list of partitions names since it could not always start by `P1` or end by `P100` (each days some partitions are dropped, some are created)

#### CLEVER SOLUTION (but does it exist?):

How can I do something like this?
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table NOT IN PARTITION(P0) WHERE ... ;`
or
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table PARTITION(*,-P0) WHERE ... ;`
or
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table LESS PARTITION(P0) WHERE ... ;`
or
`SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table EXCLUDE PARTITION(P0) WHERE ... ;`

## Is there any way to do that?

I mean a way to select all partitions expect one or some of them?
Note: I don't know in advance the value of the dateofSale. Inside the table, we have something like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    recordID NUMBER(16) NOT NULL,     --not primary
    dateOfSale DATE NOT NULL,         --unknown
    ....
    <other fields>
)
```

#### Before you answer, read the following:

1. Index usage: yes, it is already optimized, but remember, we do not know the partitioning date
2. No we won't drop records in P0, we need to keep them for at least few years (3, 5 and sometimes 10 according each country laws)
3. We can "split" P0 into several partitions, but that won't solve the issue with a global SELECT
4. We cannot move that data into a new table, we need them to be kept in this table since we have multiple services and softwares performing select in it. We would have to edit to  much code to add a query for the second table for each services and back-end.
5. We cannot do an aka `WHERE date > 2019` clause and index the date field for multiples reasons that would take too much time to explain here.

Comment: Can you let us know how many rows are there in the table and how much time it is taking. What is the table structure and the filter that you use to execute the query. Does your column used in filter criteria changes or it is fixed  ?

Comment: Can you please re-formulate your question? What I understand is: "How can I profit from *partitioning schema* when I *do not know* the the partition key?". The answer is you can't. If you want to full scan the *small partition* first and the large one only if you fail to match in the *small partitions* you are free to do this using two queries with `part_key  >= DATE'2000-01-01'` and `part_key  < DATE'2000-01-01'`

Comment: @hkandpal: number of rows are already in the initial question :) Well, globally, all tables expect P0, we have around 4M records. In total (P0 included), around 475M records

Comment: @MarmiteBomber : I know the partition key name, but I don't know the value of it :(

Comment: @MarmiteBomber : Questions edited with a part of the table content

Comment: Why do you cannot create indexes? Note, you can create indexes also one by one per partition, or skip partitions where index is not required.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit In fact we already had. But indexes are too big yet (because there are a lot of hidden fields) and also because in fact recordID is not a primary field, so it could be 2 record with same recordID but with a different update date. We don't have any field to index depending if the record is in `P0` or any partition

Comment: You can’t take advantage of the partitioning unless you have some information about the partition key value that you need to look at. This is a frequent problem when partitioning is just done for the sake of it. You can make global indexes that cover the required columns, it will work the same as an index on a non partitioned table - it won’t matter which partition the rows that match your filters belong to

Comment: @user12642493 Can you create custom objects to help the query? For example, it is possible to build a table function that dynamically builds the `PARTITION (P1,P2...)` list and returns the results. There are several ways to build that function, and the best solution depends on your Oracle version.

Comment: @JonHeller : Interrested - Running Oracle Enterprise 18c 18.0.0.0.0 - Do you think it would take less execution time if we exclude `P0` from the list ?

Answer (score 1):

The query below, ie two queries in a UNION ALL but I only want 1 row, will stop immediately a row is found. We do not need to go into the second part of the UNION ALL if we get a row in the first.

```
SQL> select * from
  2  ( select x
  3    from   t1
  4    where  x = :b1
  5    union all
  6    select x
  7    from   t2
  8    where  x = :b1
  9  )
 10  where rownum = 1
 11  /
```

See https://connor-mcdonald.com/golden-oldies/first-match-written-15-10-2007/ for a simple proof of this.

I'm assuming that you're working under the assumption that most of the time, the record you are interested in is in your most recent smaller partitions.  In the absence of any other information to hone on in the right partition, you could do

```
select * from
    ( select ...
      from   tab
      where  trans_dt >= DATE'2000-01-01'
      and    record_id = :my_record
      union all
      select x
      from   tab
      where  trans_dt < DATE'2000-01-01'
      and    record_id = :my_record
    )
where rownum = 1
```

which will only scan the big partition if we fall through and don't find it anywhere else.

But your problem does seem to be screaming out for an index to avoid all this work

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your partitioned table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE tab
  (  trans_dt       DATE
  )
 PARTITION BY RANGE (trans_dt)
 ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2000-01-01')
 , PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2000-01-02')
 , PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2000-01-03')
 , PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2000-01-04')
 );
```

If you want to skip your *large* partition `P0` in a query, you simple (as this is the first partition) constraints the partition key as `trans_dt >= DATE'2000-01-01'`

You will need two predicates and `or` to skip a partition in the *middle*

The query

```
 select * from tab
 where trans_dt >= DATE'2000-01-01';
```

Checking the *execution plan* you see the expected behaviour in `Pstart = 2`(i.e. the 1st partition is pruned).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                  | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |      |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR  |      |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     4 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| TAB  |     1 |     9 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     4 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Remember, if you scan a *partitioned table* without constraining the *partition key* you will have to scall **all partitions**.

If you know, that most of the query results are in the *recent* and small partitions, simple scan tme in the *first query*

```
 select * from tab
 where trans_dt >= DATE'2000-01-01' and <your filter>
```

and only if you fail to get the row scan the large partition

```
 select * from tab
 where trans_dt < DATE'2000-01-01' and <your filter>
```

You will get *much better* response time on average if the assumption is true that the queries refer mostly the recent data.

Comment: In that case, I would need to know in advance the date value, and I don't know them. I am looking into records ID in the table, not their associated dates values

Comment: Nope @user12642493 the date of `DATE'2000-01-01'` is defined in the tables `DDL` as the limit of the 1st partition. You may use it to skip this partition as demonstrated.

Comment: Eg. Even a recent sale can be inserted and then move to P0 because "consumed", "cancelled", whatever reasons. Also, a recent sale can be inserted but need to be keeped longer time. This is why basing a date field is impossible, it is (let say) "almost" random if a record should be move to P0

Comment: But when I am looking for record #12345678, I don't know the associate date. I am just doing a SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE recordID = '..' AND ... AND ... OR ... ; But I don't know the date of the record. When performing my SELECT, I don't have ny idea of the trans_dt value

Comment: @user12642493 - but you've shown a table partitioned by date; so saying rows are moved to p0 based on some other criteria doesn't make sense. Which is wrong? If you want to avoid scanning p0 then you apply a filter that excludes its partition key - that's the point of this answer - even if it isn't actually date-partitioned.

Comment: It makes sense. Partitioning criteria are based on insertion day, which allow us to quickly perform stats and avoid to store this data as a field in the table. We are storing recordID, but this field is not primary. Like this comments, a comment is a record right ? So old editions go to `P0` meanwhile new ones go to the today partition. If edition, we move the today record to `P0` and insert the update into the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no syntax to exclude a specific partition, you can build a pipelined table function that dynamically builds a query that uses every partition except for one.

The table function builds a query like the one below. The function uses the data dictionary view `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS` to get the partition names to build the SQL, uses dynamic SQL to execute the query, and then pipes the results back to the caller.

```
select * from my_table partition (P1) union all
select * from my_table partition (P2) union all
...
select * from my_table partition (P1000);
```

### Sample schema

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    recordID NUMBER(16) NOT NULL,     --not primary
    dateOfSale DATE NOT NULL,         --unknown
    a NUMBER
)
partition by range (dateOfSale)
(
    partition p0 values less than (date '2000-01-01'),
    partition p1 values less than (date '2000-01-02'),
    partition p2 values less than (date '2000-01-03')
);

insert into my_table
select 1,date '1999-12-31',1 from dual union all
select 2,date '2000-01-01',1 from dual union all
select 3,date '2000-01-02',1 from dual;

commit;
```

### Package and function

```
create or replace package my_table_pkg is
    type my_table_nt is table of my_table%rowtype;
    function get_everything_but_p0 return my_table_nt pipelined;
end;
/

create or replace package body my_table_pkg is
    function get_everything_but_p0 return my_table_nt pipelined is
        v_sql clob;

        v_results my_table_nt;
        v_cursor sys_refcursor;
    begin
        --Build SQL that referneces all partitions.
        for partitions in
        (
            select partition_name
            from user_tab_partitions
            where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
                and partition_name <> 'P0'
        ) loop
            v_sql := v_sql || chr(10) || 'union all select * from my_table ' ||
                'partition (' || partitions.partition_name || ')';
        end loop;

        v_sql := substr(v_sql, 12);

        --Print the query for debugging:
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

        --Gather the results in batches and pipe them out.
        open v_cursor for v_sql;

        loop
            fetch v_cursor bulk collect into v_results limit 100;
            exit when v_results.count = 0;
            for i in 1 .. v_results.count loop
                pipe row (v_results(i));
            end loop;
        end loop;

        close v_cursor;
    end;
end;
/
```

The package uses 12c's ability to define types in package specifications. If you build this in 11g or below, you'll need to create SQL types instead. This package only works for one table, but if necessary there are ways to create functions that work with any table (using Oracle data cartridge or 18c's polymorphic table functions).

### Sample query

```
SQL> select * from table(my_table_pkg.get_everything_but_p0);

  RECORDID DATEOFSAL          A
---------- --------- ----------
         2 01-JAN-00          1
         3 02-JAN-00          1
```

### Performance

This function should perform *almost* as well as the clever solution you were looking for. There will be overhead because the rows get passed through PL/SQL. But most importantly, the function builds a SQL statement that partition prunes away the large P0 partition.

One possible issue with this function is that the optimizer has no visibility inside it and can't create a good row cardinality estimate. If you use the function as part of another large SQL statement, be aware that the optimizer will blindly guess that the function returns 8168 rows. That bad cardinality guess may lead to a bad execution plan.